# Create View Statement Sequence Issue in Exported Database Script in MY SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am facing problem while exporting and importing database script from phpmyadmin or my SQL
Issue is I have multiple views in my database some views are derived from views also
Problem when I export to script, sequence of create view statement is not properly arranged so I have to manually check and executive each create statement manually.

```
EX.
View A1 – Select From Table
View A2 – Select From Table
View A3 – Select From A1 and A2
View A4 – Select From A3
```

When these are exported I get the sequence of create statements like

```
A1, A2, A4, A3 (this fails on Create A4 cause A3 is not created at the time)
```

What I want is

```
A1, A2, A3, A4
```

Comment: Since it's one time creation, why not expand views like `A3` & `A4`. Of course any change in `A1` & `A3` you need to change view definition of `A3` & `A4`.

Comment: Or, export views one by one in the order necessary and append to export `SQL`.

Comment: It’s not a onetime creation & remembering sequence is time taking process - We have a product running for multiple client and our development is in progress
Our issue is we create and test each module and deploy it to each client

Comment: who designed it that way? LOL. Only if there were options to dump tables/triggers/procedures/functions/views alphabetically. If it does, choose view names carefully.

Comment: i designed it that way cause there is a reason ! my question is how to dump data like this. My expectation was mysql should take care of this while exporting

Comment: You cannot use `should` with open sources as you're more than welcomed to add/patch a reasonable feature.

Comment: Now, I am planning to write a utility to arrange these statements in proper order, Will also study why MySQL is not doing this while other Databases do. please help if any other way !...

Comment: This seems to be phpmyadmin rather than MySQL. But why the need to recreate views constantly?